# Simple JavaScript loop wrong answer

Tags: javascript, loops

```
var v = [2, 4, 5];
var out = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
    if(v[i] % 2 == 0){
        out++;
    } else {
        out--;
    }

}
```

I get 1 as an answer, I don't understand why it's 2!

My approach:

```
for i = 0:
v[0]%2 = 2 % 2 = 0 so proceed with out++
out = 0 + 1 = 1

for i = 1:
v[1]%2 = 4 % 2 = 0 so proceed with out++
out = 1 + 1 = 2

for i = 2:
v[2]%2 = 5 % 2 != 0 so proceed with out--
i.e. out = 2 - 1 = 1
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Try to access "out". It's 1.

Comment: Cannot confirm. Sure the whole call when pasted into a console returns `2`, but have you tried to access `out` using `console.log(out)`? The reason the entire call outputs `2` is because it outputs the value of `out` *before* the `--` part. You can do the same by pasting `var out = 1; out++;` which outputs `1`.

Comment: I guess you display `i` ?

Comment: out is one, but the answer you get from the console is from the last postdecrement, 2.

Comment: @user3516885 now you can delete this question, if you wants.

Answer (score 1):

Do with a function..

```
function toReturn(array){
  var out = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] % 2 == 0){
        out++;
    } else {
        out--;
    }
  }

  return out;
}
```

the call it `toReturn([2,4,5])`

Answer (score 0):

Try this and you will see the output in each step... the final is 1

```
var v = [2, 4, 5];
var out = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
    if(v[i] % 2 === 0){ out++; } 
    else { out--; }
    console.log(out);
}
// final value again
console.log(out);
// result
// 1
// 2
// 1
// 1

// PS. you can also use a ternary (just for info)
out += v[i] % 2 ? -1 : 1;
```

Good luck
:)